# multiple triggers for bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using the latest bootstrap is there a better alternative to trigger a dropdown menu other than how I have implemented it?  Perhaps a solution that uses only data- attributes bootstrap exposes to target a specific control.

Here is the view that uses the book icon and and anchor text to trigger the same dropdown.

[image: bootstrap multiple triggers for dropdown menu]

## Code

http://plnkr.co/edit/kCbzZiEKiQZuNoLY2lNa?p=preview

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#iconTrigger,#anchorTrigger").click(function () {
        $("#ulEducationCenterDropDown").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

 <!-- trigger #1 -->
        <a id="iconTrigger" href="" title="Resources &amp; Education">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="Resources &amp; Education" />
        </a>

        <div style="display:inline;">
                <div class="btn-group" >
                   <!-- trigger #2 -->
                    <a href="" title="Resources &amp; Education" id="anchorTrigger">Resources &amp; Education <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul id="ulEducationCenterDropDown"  class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="/education-center/top-faqs">Top 12 FAQs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/education-center/home-buyers-guide">Home Buyers Guide</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/education-center/understanding-credit">Understanding Credit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/education-center/determining-rates">Determining Rates</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/education-center/mortgage-terminology">Mortgage Terminology</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/education-center/starkey-calculators">Calculators</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            <p>Resources for your home buying research.</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use the `collapse` component..

```
data-target="#ulEducationCenterDropDown" data-toggle="collapse"
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/iVDcZKYg2a

Answer (score 1):

Trying your example, i was not able to successfully open the menu, because clicking either the link or the image opened the Menu but closes directly after because the page reloads.

Maybe try this javascript code instead:

```
$(function () {
    $("#iconTrigger,#anchorTrigger").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        $("#ulEducationCenterDropDown").toggle();
    });
});
```

this prevents the default behaviour of the link - maybe this is what you were after in your question. Please let me know if not!

Best regards,

Sebastian

Comment: you are probably right to use e.preventDefault(), although, Skelly provided the answer I wanted by only using  data- attributes.  No custom jquery code at all.

Comment: Of course that is much better, thanks for your feedback!